# Using AVFoundation on watchos3 to fetching the Raw Data(Float Data)of the Microphone(Audio Input)

Tags: avfoundation, swift3, xcode8, microphone, watchos-3

in iOS Application i do this with the following code

```
inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

        let bus = 0

    inputNode!.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 2048, format: inputNode!.inputFormat(forBus: bus)) {

            (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

            let firstChannel = buffer.floatChannelData?[0]
            let arr = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: firstChannel, count:Int(buffer.frameLength))) 
    self.array.append(contentsOf: arr)
    audioEngine.prepare()

        do{
            try audioEngine.start()
        }catch {
            print("audioEngine start failed")
        }
```

and now i want to do this in my Watchos3 application but the inputnode is not available on watchos3.....
what can i do, to get the real microphone data(Float)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your `AVAudioSession` category to either  `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and activated the session?

Comment: You can't use AVAudioSession on watchOS.

Comment: ok my fault it is in watchos2 available....
but i can't combine the inputnode with audio session